# Erratic line break when printing with str.format

Tags: python, string, format

Why does the following command produce the input with the breakline. It seems the breakline appears after `{}`. I used the `format` function before and it worked fine. What happened now?

```
print('true: {}, estimated: {}'.format(number_a, number_b))

true: 3
, estimated: 3
```

Comment: `type(number_a)`

Comment: Can you print `number_a` on it's own please.  Is it actually an integer, or is it a string with a trailing newline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you're reading these numbers from a file, meaning you read in the string `'3\n'` instead of the number `3`.

Try removing the trailing newline with `str.strip`:

```
print('true: {}, estimated: {}'.format(number_a.rstrip(), number_b))
```

---

A better option would be to sanitise your data when you read it in, so you don't have to worry about things like this.

```
numbers = []
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers.append(line.strip())

a, b = numbers[:2] # first two elements

print('true: {}, estimated: {}'.format(a, b))
```

Obviously, your data may not follow the format in this example, but the takeaway is to handle these things at the source.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce this issue. Are your variables `number_a` and `number_b` string by any chance? If yes, it may contain a new line.
Try this:

```
print('true: {}, estimated: {}'.format(int(number_a), int(number_b)))
```

Example:

```
number_a = '4\n'
number_b = '5'
print('true: {}, estimated: {}'.format(int(number_a), int(number_b)))
```

Output:

```
true: 4, estimated: 5
```